# What does MATLAB's full() function do with a row parameter?

Tags: matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have a line of code as follows

```
nrma2 = full(abs(sum(A.*A',1)));
```

but `sum(...,1)` is a row. `abs()` returns only a row with absolute numbers

So, what will `full()` do?

Comment: In your case, for the vector as the argument for `full()`, then `full()` did nothing. It is usually to deal with sparse matrix, to get a full matrix.

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding you can actually have sparse 1D matrices, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`full()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/full.html) will make a full matrix out of a sparse one. A sparse matrix can be a row vector, that's just a 1 *-by-* N matrix. The code you posted presumably has `A` as a sparse matrix, or includes the `full()` in case it is not a full matrix already to ensure it becomes a full vector.

```
A = sparse([1,0;1,0])
A =
   (1,1)        1
   (2,1)        1
nrma2 = full(abs(sum(A.*A',1)))  % Full row-matrix
nrma2 =
     1     0
abs(sum(A.*A',1))  % Sparse row-matrix
ans =
   (1,1)        1
```

Specifically, from the documentation on [`full()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/full.html):

> `full`
>   Convert sparse matrix to full storage
>
> (...)
>
> `S` — Sparse matrix to convert
>   Sparse matrix to convert, specified as a matrix. If `S` is already a
>   full matrix, then `A` is identical to `S`.